# Link only visible for google and others search engine

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a little dilemma, i want to show a certain text/link only to certain user agent, like Google and Yahoo, and for other user agent to be hidden.

Like to not be visible for people that are accessing the website from Firefox, Chrome etc.

Can you help me?

Comment: if i should understand this better, you want the link to be hidden on the front end from users like tags and others right?

Comment: Yes, indeed the link should be hidden on front end. And to be fully visible to Google bot, Yahoo etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can actually hide them using css property `display: none;` after grabbing the html class or id, this will still be available to google bots and other seo crawlers because it's still available on your sitemaps, its what i personally used on my website to hide tags and other things that will make the website bulky for users.

if you can add a link to the website, i can help you better with some more codes

Comment: On website 932.ro I want to hide only for visitors the last paragraph https://prnt.sc/1zgtt28 Thank you very much!

Comment: add the display none property to this line of code or better still replace it with this line below, it should solve the problem `<div class="thrv_wrapper thrv_custom_html_shortcode" style="margin-top: 40px !important; display: none;">`